# About Predicates

Tags: sql, where-clause, predicate

A single predicate in the WHERE clauses requires AND or OR - Is this True or not true?

Comment: Would help a lot if you add a query in question

Comment: It's really not hard to answer, try to think for yourself: when do we use "AND" or "OR in the "WHERE" clause ?

Comment: It's a question...there's no question or data attached to this question.

Comment: alfasin...We don't use AND or OR in the WHERE clause right?

Comment: What is a ***single*** predicate?

Comment: PM, there's no predicate. It's just a question...

Comment: This is not true.